# How to use Logstash cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, logstash, chef-solo

I'm trying to use https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash cookbook and running
Chef solo, my node.json looks like this:

```
{    
"logstash": {
"instance_default":{
  "config_templates_cookbook": "aws-logstash",
  "inputs": [{"file": {"path":"/var/log/messages","type":"messages"}}],
  "config_templates": {"myagent": "agent.conf.erb"}
  }},
 "run_list": ["recipe[logstash::agent]"]}
```

The only attributes I can override are config_templates_cookbook and config_template.  I am not able to define inputs, filters or outputs via variables.  Sure defining all options under agent.conf.erb could work but it defeats the purpose of the cookbook a bit.  Can anybody help with a way to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't clearly get you question. check [`inputs`,`filters` and `outputs` here](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L73-L75)

Comment: node.json already contains "inputs": [{"file": {"path":"/var/log/messages","type":"messages"}}], but config doesn't get generated.

Comment: You can use chef roles / environments to override these values for you specific use case

Comment: How do I override it?  The above examples overrides them through node attributes.  I also tried doing it with a role but config file does not get created.  When run it says 'logstash_config[agent] action create (up to date)' and no config (